# Is a pay-version of LINQPad required to use custom assemblies?

Tags: linqpad

I just ran into LINQPad today and was trying to add a connection using my own LINQ to SQL assembly. I've specified the path, the full name, the server, and the auth method but the OK button to save it never enables. Either there is something wrong with my DLL or perhaps this feature is only available in one of the paid editions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm an idiot and didn't specify the database. I could vote to delete this question but maybe someone else will have a similar moment and this will help them out.